# Pass column name as a parameter

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to pass a column name from front end to back end in my code. i'm using c# with oracle and when i pass the column name as a parameter, it gives an error and it's because the column name is used as a string in here and i need to know how to fix this. here is my code,

```
PROCEDURE PR_GETCLIENTCONTRACTDATA(INSTRFIELD IN VARCHAR2,INSTRCONTRACTNO IN VARCHAR2,CUR_OUTPUT OUT T_CURSOR)--ADDED BY DIDULA 25/10/2017 
IS
    BEGIN
        OPEN CUR_OUTPUT FOR
SELECT c.con_no,
       DECODE (a.clm_cori,
               '1', a.clm_cltitle || ' ' || a.clm_initialsfull || ' '
                || a.clm_name,
               a.clm_name
              ) cliname,
       a.clm_code,
       (   a.clm_permaddline1
        || '|'
        || a.clm_permaddline2
        || '|'
        || COALESCE (a.clm_permaddline3, a.clm_permaddline4)
        || '|'
        || NULLIF ((a.clm_permaddline4),
                   COALESCE (a.clm_permaddline3, a.clm_permaddline4)
                  )
       ) address
  FROM leaseinfo.tblcontracts c, corpinfo.tblclientmain a
 WHERE a.clm_code = c.con_clmcode
   AND INSTRFIELD = INSTRCONTRACTNO; ***here INSTRFIELD is the column name 
                                        that i need to pass***

END PR_GETCLIENTCONTRACTDATA;
```

Comment: Can you post error message?

Comment: no error for this. it works fine if i manually add the values to INSTRFIELD and INSTRCONTRACTNO. the problem is INSTRFIELD is a column name.it should be. as ab example one value for INSTRFIELD is con_number. it should be con_number. but here it take as 'con_number'. the problem is the single quotes

Comment: _"it gives an error"_ vs _"no error for this."_ Which is it?

Comment: sorry it was my bad that mentioned "it gives an error". but problem is how do i use the string parameter as a column name

Comment: Pls share your calling statement. Alternatively try once "AND TABLENAME.INSTRFIELD = INSTRCONTRACTNO; " in the procedure. But share the calling statement of C#.

Comment: @smshafiqulislam The OP is trying to use dynamic SQL - `INSTRFIELD` is the procedure parameter containing the dynamic column name and is not a column on the table.

Answer (score 1):

Whitelist the column names:

```
PROCEDURE PR_GETCLIENTCONTRACTDATA(
  INSTRFIELD      IN  VARCHAR2,
  INSTRCONTRACTNO IN  VARCHAR2,
  CUR_OUTPUT      OUT T_CURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN CUR_OUTPUT FOR
    SELECT -- your select clauses
    FROM   leaseinfo.tblcontracts c,
           INNER JOIN corpinfo.tblclientmain a -- ANSI join syntax
           ON a.clm_code = c.con_clmcode
    WHERE  CASE INSTRFIELD 
           WHEN 'COLUMNA' THEN ColumnA
           WHEN 'COLUMNB' THEN ColumnB
           WHEN 'COLUMNC' THEN ColumnC
           END = INSTRCONTRACTNO;
END PR_GETCLIENTCONTRACTDATA;
/
```

Comment: @Didu If this or any other answer has solved your problem then you can mark the question as solved by clicking on the check mark below the voting buttons (to the left of the answer) - this lets other people know your preferred solution and that the issue has been satisfactorily solved.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `OPEN cur FOR ...` you can pass a string, i.e.

```
PROCEDURE PR_GETCLIENTCONTRACTDATA(INSTRFIELD IN VARCHAR2,INSTRCONTRACTNO IN VARCHAR2,CUR_OUTPUT OUT T_CURSOR)
IS
 BEGIN
    OPEN CUR_OUTPUT FOR
      'SELECT c.con_no,
       DECODE (a.clm_cori,
               ''1'', a.clm_cltitle || '' '' || a.clm_initialsfull || '' ''
                || a.clm_name,
               a.clm_name
              ) cliname,
       a.clm_code,
       (   a.clm_permaddline1
        || ''|''
        || a.clm_permaddline2
        || ''|''
        || COALESCE (a.clm_permaddline3, a.clm_permaddline4)
        || ''|''
        || NULLIF ((a.clm_permaddline4),
                   COALESCE (a.clm_permaddline3, a.clm_permaddline4)
                  )
       ) address
       FROM leaseinfo.tblcontracts c
           JOIN corpinfo.tblclientmain a ON a.clm_code = c.con_clmcode
       WHERE '||DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME(INSTRFIELD)||' = :INSTRCONTRACTNO)' 
   USING INSTRCONTRACTNO;

END PR_GETCLIENTCONTRACTDATA;
```

Comment: This is a bad idea to just accept arbitrary strings without any defensive coding - what happens if the value passed in is "`EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM password_table WHERE hash = '123456' ) OR 1`"?

Comment: @MT0 Of course this does not work, I assumed `INSTRCONTRACTNO` is always a  single literal. I think your solution has the same limitation.

Comment: It will work - You would end up with the final line `WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM password_table WHERE hash = '123456' ) OR 1 = :INSTRCONTRACTNO` and `INSTRCONTACTNO` is a single bind variable and it is being compared to `1` another literal but you have just allowed a malicious user to insert any arbitrary SQL select statements and bypass your expected filter conditions on your query by not applying any defensive coding to the `INSTRFIELD` parameter.

Comment: @MT0 or you may verify value of `INSTRFIELD` with [DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_assert.htm#ARPLS65389)

Comment: That would be a good thing to add to your answer (rather than just in comments) - without it all sorts of bad things can occur.